# Saving excel as spreadsheet xml 2003 with epplus

Tags: c#, excel, xml, epplus

I'm working with EPPlus.

But I'm having an issue with the file type, because where I'm working, we use a management system which only read `SpreadSheet XML 2003` as excel file.

I try save the document as XML but didn't get the SpreadSheet XML 2003 excel format

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "CodigoInteligente", "Articulos.xml");
var archivo = new FileInfo(path);
```

How can I generate Excel with spreadsheet xml 2003 format with epplus? or which library can I use?

Comment: Do you mean xlx?  Xml is much different from Excel.

Comment: I don't think EPPLus will write that format. But if I look at the [spec for that SpreadsheetML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140066(v=office.10)) I suspect you could start with saving the file as XLSX and then read the file at `xl\worksheets\Sheet1.xml` (remember that xlsx is just a zip file), and apply an XSLT transformation. Not trivial but if nothing else gets offered worth trying.

Comment: @jdweng excel has an old xml format

Comment: @rene do you mind with xslt transformation? I dont understand, thanks!

Comment: An XSLT transformation will take the current XML format and transform it in the old one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-transformations but you'll have to provide the so called XSLT transformation stylesheet which is the hardest part.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will try!

Comment: @SouXin: Not a duplicate of that post. This question asks specifically about using EPPlus to save as a specific Excel version file, which is not the same as the post you've used as a duplicate (twice) is asking.

Comment: You're right. It's not XML but XLS. My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I do not want to use this solution because it uses `Microsoft.Office.Interop` and not all computers have excel installed, however, I answer the question, because someone in my situation, it may be useful.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook book = null;
bool status = false;
try 
    { 
    var originalPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "CodigoInteligente" , "Originales" , "Articulos.xls");
    var oldFile = new FileInfo(originalPath);
    if (!oldFile.Exists)
        {
            return false;
        }
    var newPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "CodigoInteligente", "Articulos.xls");
    var newFile = new FileInfo(newPath);
    if (newFile.Exists)
        {
        if (IsFileLocked(newFile))
            {
                return false;
            }
        newFile.Delete();
        }
    book = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(originalPath);
    book.SaveAs(newPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet);
    status = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Hubo un error");
        Logs.agregarLog(ex);
        return false;
    }
    finally
        {                
        book.Close(false);
        xlApp.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(book);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
return status;
```